InvalidParameterException: Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn
I am facing below error while creating ECS service. I have to explain each new permission added. So I can't use * anywhere.
Another point is, all my nodes showing Agent disconnected.
creating ECS Service (service-integ): InvalidParameterException: 
Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn.
Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.

Service Role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "service_policy" {
  name = "service-policy-${var.environment}"
  role = aws_iam_role.service_role.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "ECRPull"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        ]
        Resource = "${data.aws_ecr_repository.service_repository.arn}"
      },
      {
        Sid    = "ECRAuthToken"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Sid    = "CloudWatchLogs"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ]
        Resource = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.service_log_group.arn}"
      },
      {
        Sid    = "SSMParams"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "ssm:GetParameter",
          "ssm:GetParameters"
        ]
        Resource = [
          "${aws_ssm_parameter.user_id.arn}",
          "${aws_ssm_parameter.user_secret.arn}"
        ]
      },
      {
        Sid    = "ELBAccess"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
          "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
          "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
          "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
          "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"
        ]
        Resource = [
          "${var.service_nlb_arn}"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "service_role" {
  name = "service-role-${var.environment}"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = ["ecs.amazonaws.com"]
        }
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      "Name" = "service-role-${var.environment}"
    },
  )

}

Service (task def not added)
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name                = "service-${var.environment}"
  cluster             = var.ecs_cluster_id
  scheduling_strategy = "DAEMON"
  iam_role            = aws_iam_role.service_role.arn

  #Rolling updates
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50

  # Track the latest ACTIVE revision
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.service_task.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.service_task.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.service_task_data.revision}")}"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.service_tg.arn
    container_name   = "service-task-${var.environment}"
    container_port   = local.container_port
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      desired_count
    ]
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

IAM for ECR Node (instance profile)
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_access" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ssm:GetParameter",
      "ssm:GetParameters",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ssm:${var.aws_region}:${local.account_id}:parameter/*"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ecr:${var.aws_region}:${local.account_id}:repository/${var.ecr_prefix}",
      "arn:aws:ecr:${var.aws_region}:${local.account_id}:repository/${var.environment}/*",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ecs:TagResource",
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_ecs_cluster.shared_cluster.arn
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "ecs:CreateAction"

      values = [
        "CreateCluster",
        "RegisterContainerInstance",
      ]
    }
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ecs:CreateCluster",
      "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
      "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
      "ecs:Poll",
      "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
      "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
      "ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState",
      "ecs:Submit*",
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_ecs_cluster.shared_cluster.arn
    ]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:DescribeTags",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents"
    ]
    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "shared_cluster_role" {
  name = "prl-shared-cluster-role-${var.environment}"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
 {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
     "Service": ["ecs.amazonaws.com", "ec2.amazonaws.com", "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com", "ssm.amazonaws.com"]
   },
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
  ]
}
EOF

  inline_policy {
    name   = "ssmparams"
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_access.json
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      "Name" = "shared-cluster-role-${var.environment}"
    },
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "shared_cluster_profile" {
  name = "shared-cluster-profile-${var.environment}"
  role = aws_iam_role.shared_cluster_role.name
}

